# CSS tabs menu looks ugly when changing browser-zoom

Tags: html, css, tabs

Please look at my CSS Tabs menu: http://jsfiddle.net/NoGo/3Spru/

It uses the YAML 4 CSS Framework form yaml.de (Edit 2019: not actively developed anymore)

The Tabs are: Home | Users | Map

My HTML:

```
<nav>
    <div class="ym-wrapper">
        <div class="ym-wbox">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div>Home <i class="icon-home"></i></div>
                        <span>Go to Main Page</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#" class="">
                        <div>Users <i class="icon-search"></i></div>
                        <span>Search User Accounts</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <div>Map <i class="icon-globe"></i></div>
                        <span>Users near you</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="ym-clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The CSS:

```
header nav {
    clear: both;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding-top:10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #CA278C;
}
header nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    display:inline;
}
header nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-top: 2px solid transparent;
    margin: 0 5px -2px 0;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #CA278C;
    line-height: 180%;
}
header nav ul li.active,
header nav ul li:hover {
    border-top: 2px solid #CA278C;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: #fff;
}
header nav ul li.active {
    border-right: 2px solid #CA278C;
    border-left: 2px solid #CA278C;
}
header nav ul li a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px 16px;
}
header nav ul li a div {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
}
header nav ul li a span {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #999
}
header nav [class^="icon-"],
header nav [class*=" icon-"] {
    vertical-align: baseline;
    line-height: inherit;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

My problem: When I change browser zoom, the bottom-line looks ugly. Is there a better way than working with `margin-bottom: -2px` on `li` elements?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/3Spru/3/ -- is this acceptable?

Comment: @Explosion Pills: no, sorry, it destroys the "tabs" concept.

Comment: what do you mean?  The example you posted seems exactly the same at 100% zoom

Comment: yours looks like this in my firefox: http://awesomescreenshot.com/08618spn64 - mine like this: http://awesomescreenshot.com/00718spr47

Comment: you mean it's shorter?

Comment: No, i mean the bottom line should be interrupted in order to have a "tabs" look ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get it to look a lot better by using [subpixel positioning](http://css3wizardry.com/2010/10/05/subpixel-rendering-2/) and setting the `margin-bottom`  and `border-width` to `-1.5px` and `1.5px` respectively. It [looks fine here at <kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/3Spru/5/) - with minimal effort - on `100%` up to somewhere close to `200%`, and you could probably get it to look even better at other zoom levels by going further down the subpixel rendering path.

But then it dawned on me that you don't really need to have that bottom border on the inactive tabs, just set the `margin-bottom` on the tabs to `0px` and then set the `margin-bottom` at the `.active` and `:hover` class to `-2px`. This will automatically look fine on any zoom level, as you won't have to worry about 'lineing up the lines' at all. [Here's a <kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/3Spru/7/) for this approach.

```
header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  line-height: 180%;
  position: relative;
}
header nav ul li.active,
header nav ul li:hover {
  border-top: 2px solid #CA278C;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFF;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: -2px;    
}
```

Comment: Yes, That seems to be the best easiest solution. thank you! :-)