# CSS tabs look bad when zooming browser window

Tags: css

I have a CSS "tab bar" with a bottom border. The active tab should have a "hole" in the bottom border. I've implemented this by a negative bottom margin and a bottom border the same colour as the background.

This looks fine at normal browser zoom:

[image: Looking good]

But looks bad in various ways in Chrome and Safari if I zoom the browser window:

[image: Looking bad]

How do I make it not look bad when zooming? Ideally without introducing additional markup. I would like for it to work at least in all modern browsers.

Here's the code (JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4utwsvt2/):

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab active">Foo</div>
    <div class="tab">Bar</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {  background: #fff; }

.tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 5px -1px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tab.active {
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

I've tried decimal pixel values [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16409166/6962) with no luck (JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1gyz7me5/1/).

I've tried using `position: relative` instead of a negative margin, with no luck (looks good in Chrome but not Safari – JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qwkvxdj4/).

I've tried using `translate` instead of a negative margin, with no luck (JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qwkvxdj4/1/).

Comment: When you say Safari, do you mean Safari on Windows, or Mac OSx, or iOS? Note that the Windows version is several versions behind and no longer supported. Also, using `translate` does not look good in Chrome, either, from 125-175%.

Comment: Make the border-bottom 2px :D

Comment: This is Chrome 59.0.3071.115 and Safari 10.1.1 (12603.2.4) on macOS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73). You're right about `translate` – I'll edit the question. Thank you!

Comment: as @Keloo suggested, with a border bottom of 2px seem to work fine on chrome (can't test on safari tho) : https://jsfiddle.net/0dn5cyc6/

Comment: @Nick I'm afraid I'm seeing major issues in Safari with that solution, and some minor issues in Chrome (the vertical bars of the active tab continue below the line, though half transparent).

Comment: Setting a background colour on the tabs (JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qwkvxdj4/3/) seems to make things a little better. Rendering won't be pixel perfect, but at least the bottom border won't show through the tab if the tab renders a little too far down on the page. Though in my real-life more complicated case, I've also seen issues where it renders too far up…

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on Chrome zoom levels except for 75% and 33% and 20%:

```
 body {  background: #fff; }

.tabs {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}

.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.tab.active {
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

The problem is "hiding" the bottom border with the tab's bottom border to appear active. At certain zoom levels, the aesthetic will only partially cover (if at all) the bottom border. By removing the negative margin and making the position relative, you're moving the tabs after the page has rendered, which is a decent pseudo-fix for zooming in at least.

Comment: Thank you. I'm afraid I tried this in https://jsfiddle.net/qwkvxdj4/ (linked from the question) and noted it doesn't fix the issue in Safari. (Neither `top: 1px` nor `bottom: -1px`.)